# Como trocar o avatar AngularJS usando imagem da storage?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Criando um app com AngularJS e gostaria que o usuário escolhesse uma foto de sua storage para inserir como imagem de seu perfil, ou seja, quero buscar a imagem na memória interna. É possível?

```
$scope.pegaArquivo = function (files) {
    var imgLocal = document.getElementById('imgLocal')
    var file = files[0];
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.file = file;

    localStorage.setItem('object',JSON.stringify(file)); 
    this.quickOrder.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('object')));
    return file;

    imgLocal.appendChild(img)

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function (aImg) { return function (e) { aImg.src = e.target.result; }; })(img);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

Comment: Sim, é só vc recuperar a lista de imagens que está no LocalStorage, disponibilizar pro usuário escolher passar o id da imagem escolhida pro getItem

Comment: Desculpa DiegoAugusto não entendi como fazer isto, poderia deixar um exemplo?

Comment: A pergunta esta um tanto quanto confusa.

Comment: Olá Ronaldo, pelo que eu entendi você está buscando primeiramente salvar uma imagem na *storage* e depois recuperá-la para exibir em uma *tag* `img`, é isso? Se sim, dê uma olhada [nessa resposta do SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19183658/664577).